# LLVM New Pass Manager - custom pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I had a custom pass with the legacy LLVM pass manager using the llvm::CallGraphSCC, I'm trying to replace it with the New Pass Manager but I don't find how to access the llvm::CallGraphSCC. I need to loop over each node of the graph in my custom pass.

Any idea?

Old Pass Manager

```
class AnnotateInternalFunctionsPass : public llvm::CallGraphSCCPass {
 public:
  static char ID;
  AnnotateInternalFunctionsPass() : CallGraphSCCPass(ID) {}

  bool runOnSCC(llvm::CallGraphSCC& SCC) override {
    
    // iterate the call graph
    for (auto& node : SCC) {
```

New Pass Manager

```
class AnnotateInternalFunctionsPass
    : public llvm::PassInfoMixin<AnnotateInternalFunctionsPass> {
 public:
  static char ID;

  llvm::PreservedAnalyses run(llvm::Function& F, llvm::FunctionAnalysisManager& AM) {
    
    for (auto& node : SCC) { // how to get access to SCC from F or AM?
```

Tried a few things like this without success:

`llvm::CallGraph& SCC = getAnalysis<llvm::CallGraphWrapperPass>().getCallGraphSCC();`

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you created a CallGraphSCCPass using the old pass manager. In your second example you created a FunctionPass using the new pass manager. Are you sure you want to create a FunctionPass?

If you want to create a CallGraphSCCPass using the new pass manager, take a look at this example taken from LLVM's code base ([CallGraphSCCPass example](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Passes/PassBuilder.cpp#L304)).

```
/// No-op CGSCC pass which does nothing.
struct NoOpCGSCCPass : PassInfoMixin<NoOpCGSCCPass> {
  PreservedAnalyses run(LazyCallGraph::SCC &C, CGSCCAnalysisManager &,
                        LazyCallGraph &, CGSCCUpdateResult &UR) {
    return PreservedAnalyses::all();
  }
  static StringRef name() { return "NoOpCGSCCPass"; }
};
```